# In DotNetNuke, what is the difference between a authentication provider and membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I'm working with a product owner who has an existing ASP.NET web application that does some reporting.  For sake of discussion, let's call this "WebApp1."

She has requested that we provide a DotNetNuke portal to provide forum functionality.

As part of the requirements, the main login screen for the DotNetNuke portal should authenticate the user against the user database of "WebApp1."  The existing users table of "WebApp1" has hashed passwords.

As I have been researching these requirements, I have discovered that both MemberShipProvider pattern and AuthenticationProvider seem to address the same requirements.

From a DotNetNuke perspective, what is the difference between these providers?  Which pattern introduces the least complexity?

Please know that my experience with DotNetNuke is limited.

Please know that I'm thankful to the StackOverflow community for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication only handles logging in (who are you {username} and do you have the right password).

Membership handles that plus more like authorization (now that I know who you are,are you allowed to do that)

Answer (score 0):

---- I WORK FOR [PowerDNN.com](http://www.POWERDNN.com) ----

Hi Michael,
A few months ago I wrote a membership provider to do something similar where we were connecting a DotNetNuke website to a linux based backend system for authorization.  I felt like I cheated a little bit, but my solution worked out pretty good.

Here's what I did:
1)  I inherited from DotNetNuke's membership provider.
2)  I overrode the "Login" function with custom code.
2.1)  It finds the user in the remote system.
2.2)  It verifies the credentials of the remote user.
2.3)  It creates the user in DNN if it doesn't already exist.
2.4)  It syncs any permissions into DNN
2.5)  I log the user in.

As an FYI, when I create the local user, I give it a prefix like "CUSTOM-#####" where ##### is their ID in the remote system.  That way I can easily tell which users are "regular" dnn users and which users are synced users.

Also, if I can't find the user in the remote DB, then I authenticate against DNN itself (that way users like 'Host' and 'Admin' also work).

I hope this helps!